# Simple volume control on Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, volume-control

Is there some way to have a simple volume control on Lollipop? It was bad enough when each media stream had it's own volume, but the addition of notification priorities has made the overhead with Android volume management impractical.

With this in mind, is there some utility, app, Tasker profile, etc that will make it so when I press the "volume down" key on my phone, all streams will get quieter, and when I press the "volume up" key on my phone, all streams will get louder?

I would like this to be completely context agnostic; if I try and decrease the volume while media is playing, I'd like it to also decrease the ringer volume, and visa-versa.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to root and install the xposed framework. From there, you can install gravitybox or some alternative that offers unified volume controls.

Comment: The problem with what OP is suggesting is that generally ringer, media and alarm volume all have different scales, which vary between devices: for example, on my phone the ringer volume goes from 0 to 7, but the media volume goes from 0 to 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A root tweak is one option but if you don't want to do this, SoundHUD (avaliable [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.soundhud)) will bring more traditional volume controls back to Lollipop. The app has lots of configuration options too.

Comment: It has has been pulled from the play store.  [Simple Volume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.marextafl.mx.simplevolume) might do the trick.